# На странице удалённых сообщений заголовок вопроса не совпадает с фактическим заголовком вопроса

Tags: дефект, удаление-вопросов, 10k-tools

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В инструментах заголовок: **.csv -> mysql, через python скрипт?**

А по факту: [Заполнение бд на mysql с помощью CSV файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924275/15479).

Comment: Тоже не та ссылка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ссылка, которая присутствует для выделенного вопроса, исходно ведёт на его родной адрес на Мете, но из-за переноса вопроса происходит редирект на основной сайт, где заголовок вопроса уже изменён. Возможно, здесь стоило бы изменить текущую ссылку добавкой `?noredirect=1` в конце, тогда она будет вести на [сообщение, имевшееся на момент переноса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8433/csv-mysql-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-python-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82?noredirect=1). Такую же ссылку, в принципе, можно получить и в [списке ревизий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/924275/revisions), если перейти из блока, описывающего действие по переносу:

> [image: ссылка]